# Django Piston : Define the priority of the returned elements

Tags: django, django-piston

Let's take this sample :

```
url(r'^test[/]$', test_handler, { 'emitter_format': 'xml' }),
```

With the following handler :

```
class testHandler(BaseHandler):
    allowed_methods = ('GET',)
    def read(self, request):
        return {'element': 'I want to be first', 'test': 'No way', }
```

The result when calling the API will be :

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response><test>No way</test><element>I want to be first</element></response>
```

I don't want to get the 'No way' in first place, so how to define an order priority on the elements returned ?

Comment: I'd like to know your solution. please post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by creating my own Emitter :

```
class CustomXmlEmitter(Emitter):
    def _to_xml(self, xml, data):
        if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):            
            for item in data:
                self._to_xml(xml, item)
        elif isinstance(data, dict):
            for key, value in data.iteritems():
                xml.startElement(key, {})
                self._to_xml(xml, value)
                xml.endElement(key)
        else:
            xml.characters(smart_unicode(data))

    def render(self, request):
        stream = StringIO.StringIO()
        xml = SimplerXMLGenerator(stream, "utf-8")
        xml.startDocument()
        xml.startElement("response", {})
        self._to_xml(xml, self.construct())
        xml.endElement("response")
        xml.endDocument()
        return stream.getvalue()
Emitter.register('custom_xml', CustomXmlEmitter, 'text/xml; charset=utf-8')
Mimer.register(lambda *a: None, ('text/xml',))
```

and return the element nested this way :

```
return [{'element': 'I want to be first'}, {'test': 'No way', }]
```